# android - How to post image and url on google+ stream?

Tags: android, google-plus

I am newbie to Google+. I was successfully run the sample application. Now I would like to know about how to post images and url on google+ stream. Is it possible? if yes, please help me how to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to post directly to the Google+ Stream.  However, you can use a Share button to allow users to share your app's content.  And with an Interactive Post, you can prefill the text and up to 10 recipients of the share, so that your content is shared with the right audience.

You can learn about these shares at https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive.